# Datagridview Cell Backcolor formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview, formatting, cell

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string kesim = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["kesim"].Value);

                if (kesim == "True")
                {


                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["kesim"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["kesim"].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["kesim", row.Index].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["kesim", row.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;          
                 }
               else
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["kesim"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["kesim"].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["kesim", row.Index].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["kesim", row.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;      
                }
                string torna = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["torna"].Value);

                if (torna == "True")
                {


                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["torna"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["torna"].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["torna", row.Index].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["torna", row.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
              else
                {


                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["torna"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["torna"].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["torna", row.Index].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1["torna", row.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
```

My first row  ;

http://prntscr.com/4csw89

My second row ;

http://prntscr.com/4cswco

i want to if the cell value is true i want to change the back color to green else red.

I took the code from this link ;

[Using a dynamic list of Custom Object and can't dynamically change dataGrid's cells properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502071/using-a-dynamic-list-of-custom-object-and-cant-dynamically-change-datagrids-ce)

Please help my question

Comment: Use the [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: are you serious ? i already using this. my code is on my question

Comment: You didn't *show us* where you are using this code.  Don't loop through the rows.  Just format the cell you get from the DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs parameter.

Comment: No, you did not include the event header in your code.

Comment: sorry guys how can i do this with cellformatting ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop through all the rows when using the CellFormatting event, since that event will give you the ColumnIndex and the RowIndex of the cell being modified.  Just format the cell that needs the formatting:

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Value != null) {
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "kesim" | 
        dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "torna" ) {
      if (e.Value.ToString() == "True") {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
      } else {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MerihDursun What am I supposed to do with that comment?  Is the event wired up?  What does "not working" mean?  What happens when you step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: event successfully starting end ending but formatting isnt working

Comment: @MerihDursun You mean the code hits one of the `e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color` lines but the color of the cell still doesn't change?

Comment: how can i step through the code with the debugger ?

Comment: @MerihDursun You have to learn that.  Click on the margin of the line of code where you want the code to stop to get the red circle to show up.  When the code hits it, you can use F8 to step into each line and examine the values of what you are seeing by hovering your mouse over them.

Comment: @MerihDursun Right.  Check the values why when the code is paused.  There you will see why it's not hitting those lines.  It sounds like your *column names* aren't "kesim" or "torna".  CellFormatting will get hit a lot during runtime since a mouseover will trigger it, too, btw.

Comment: string select = "SELECT * FROM siparisler";

                FbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new FbDataAdapter(); //c.con is the connection string

               // FbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new  FbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(select, myConnection1);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: its my data adapter code so i havent got any columns. Columns are created automaticly. kesim and torna is my table columns.

Comment: @MerihDursun Try changing the code to check for capitalized versions: "KESIM" and "TORNA".  Case matters.